# Failed to load plugin 'react' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, eslint, bitbucket-pipelines

When run locally, it seems to work fine but crashes when its on pipeline

[image]

EDIT: After removing npx, it produces a different error:

[image]

I have followed the advice of installing the plugin:

```
npm install eslint-plugin-react@latest --save-dev
```

But seeps to repeat itself.

Here's my retracted bitbucket-pipelines.yml config:

```
  - step:
          name: CI
          caches:
              - node
          script:
              - npm install
              - npm run lint
              - npm run test
```

eqautes to package.json

```
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.tsx src --ignore-pattern node_modules/",
    "test": "jest --verbose --colors --coverage",
```

Here's my eslint config file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
          "extensions": [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"],
          "paths": ["src"]
        }
      }
    },
    "rules": {
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `npx` to lint? And what do the package file and install step say, *are* those plugins installed?

Comment: I've read that it is intended to run a local version of a dependency rather than a global counterpart. Is that right?

Comment: If it *is* locally installed, calling it directly `"lint": "eslint ..."` will work too.

Comment: It gave me a different error now: https://i.imgur.com/eJJbu2F.png . I have followed and installed but to no avail

Comment: Please put a [mre] in the question. Screenshots are not useful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated the question

Comment: That appears to be the *same* error, that `eslint-plugin-react` isn't installed. This is still mostly screenshot and not a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by removing **NODE_ENV** in pipelines's .env due to this:

> npm install (in package directory, no arguments):
>
> Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.
>
> In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it
>   installs the current package context (ie, the current working
>   directory) as a global package.
>
> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as
>   dependencies in package.json.
>
> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable
>   is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in
>   devDependencies.
>
> NOTE: The --production flag has no particular meaning when adding a
>   dependency to a project.

Comment: You might consider linking to the docs, for further reading: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 2):

An update to Visual Studio Code fixed this for me.

I was unwittingly on a 2 year old version.

Answer (score 0):

it happened to to.

tried hard to find the answer.

Apparently, eslint searchs for a roots in the working directory, or something like that, to find the modules to import.

It happens that i've had two apps in my project folder, and only one had the eslintrc.josn.

I fixed to use eslint on the entire project oppening the vs settings.json and add the following:

"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./app1","./app2"...]

if u have more than one app on ur project folder, u should try it